# WebSocket callback to answer to message

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I am playing with a simple exercise with WebSockets. I have a NodeJS script that listens on a WebSocket, receives a file name, opens the file, and sends the content of the file back to the client through the WebSocket.

Here is the code:

```
var websocket_server = require('ws').Server;
var server = new websocket_server({port: 1234});

var fs = require('fs');

server.on('connection', function connection(socket)
{
  socket.on('message', function request(file_name)
  {
    fs.readFile(file_name, function(error, data)
    {
      if(error)
        throw error;

      socket.send(data, {binary: true});
    });
  });
});
```

On the client side, I use a WebSocket to load an image and display it in the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Little Project</title>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
        var ws = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:1234");
        ws.binarytype = "blob";
        ws.onmessage = function(event)
        {
            var img = document.createElement("img");
            img.src = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(event.data);
            document.body.appendChild(img);
        }

        ws.onopen = function(event)
        {
            ws.send("image1.jpg")
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, this example works fine, and I am happy. What makes me sad is that I would now like to ask the server for multiple images, and to do something with each.

I know that I could serialize all my requests by doing something like:

```
ws.onmessage = function(event)
{
    // Do something with image1.jpg
    ws.onmessage = function(event)
    {
        // Do something with image2.jpg
        // And so on
    }
    ws.send("image2.jpg");
};
ws.send("image1.jpg");
```

But this is serial, which adds overhead and so on. What I would like to get is something like:

```
ws.send("image1.jpg", function(event)
{
    // Do something with image1.jpg
});

ws.send("image2.jpg", function(event)
{
    // Do something with image2.jpg
});

// And so on
```

I have no clue on how to do this neither on the client nor on the server, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Why don't you just send images as json-encoded array and then handle it on server-side? I've not run this code, but it should work.

```
let images = [
    "image1.jpg",
    "image2.jpg",
];

ws.send(JSON.stringify(images), function(event)
{
    // Do something with images
});
```

Comment: it's not working, because send method on client accepts only one parameter and it's data string https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/WebSocket

Comment: @matteo... you marked as accepted an incorrect answer

Answer (score 0):

You should use the library [`websockets-callback`](https://github.com/aidv/websockets-callback) which does exactly what you want.

Here is part of the code that is included in the demo:

```
function onTestProgressClick(){
    var milliseconds = document.getElementById("callbackDelay").value;

    //magic starts here
    wsc.send({cmd: 'progress'},
        function(response){
            document.getElementById("ws_response").innerHTML = 'Progress test completed!';
        },

        function(response){
            document.getElementById("progressBar").value = response.progress;
        }
    )
}
```